# Как в swift сделать скриншот главного экрана IOS?

Tags: ios, swift

Возможно ли при запуске приложения сделать скриншот **iOS Home Page** и отобразить его? Какими средствами это можно сделать, в какую сторону гуглить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если под "сделать скриншот главного экрана iOS при запуске приложения" понимается сделать скриншот экрана home самой iOS с иконками приложений, то нет, нельзя.

Comment: Да, именно это имел ввиду. Мне нужно что бы после запуска приложения появлялся "home самой iOS с иконками приложений" и по верх него можно было показать попапы и подобное. Или может помните на windows была программка, которая подменяла рабочий стол скриншетом и можно было разрисовать рабочий стол или разбить молотком или поджечь иконки и т.д. Возможно как то подобное реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Можно делать скриншот так (скриншот сохраняется в фотоальбом пользователя):

```
func takeScreenshot(_ shouldSave: Bool = true) -> UIImage? {
        var screenshotImage :UIImage?
        let layer = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.layer
        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return nil}
        layer.render(in:context)
        screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        if let image = screenshotImage, shouldSave {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
        }
        return screenshotImage
    }
```

После получения `UIImage` скриншота можно отобразить с помощью `UIImageView`.

Comment: Не могу заставить ваше решение работать. Хочу уточнить что делаю в контексте nativescript плагина и мне выкидывает ошибку. Ругается на восклицательный знак. Без него layer возвращает undefined. Пробывал поменять на оператор элвиса но тоже не работает.

Comment: Судя по комментарию ниже это не реально реализовать.

Comment: @DmitryZaharov согласно уточнению скриншот iOS home page сделать нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из комментария к ответу, у Вас примерно 2 варианта:

1. Попросить пользователя чтобы он сам сделал скриншот и выбрал его из галереи. Дальше работать уже с этим скриншотом в приложении.
2. Предоставить набор каких-нибудь стандартных изображений "Рабочего стола" в приложении и с выбранным работать.